# aspnetbolierplate Migrator console application appsettings

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Is it possible to run AspnetBoilerplate CompanyName?ProjectName.Migrator as per environment and how?

What I can see is that it can only read settings from appsettings.json but not from appsettings.{Environment}.json for example. This is totally not affordable for CI/CD scenario where I plan to run Migrator as a part of the process.

Any help or idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Migrator gets the host connection string from its own appsettings.json file. In the beginning, it will be the same in the appsettings.json in the .Web.Host project. Be sure that the connection string in the config file is the database you want. After getting the host connection string, it first creates the host database and applies migrations if they don't already exist. It then gets the connection strings of the tenant databases and runs migrations against those databases. It skips a tenant if it does not have a dedicated database or its database has already been migrated by another tenant (for shared databases between multiple tenants).

You can use this tool on the development or on the production environment to migrate databases on deployment instead of EntityFramework's own tooling (which requires some configuration and can only work for a single database/tenant in one run).

You can refer [this](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-Framework-Core) document related to connection string.

Comment: Vivek, that's really good explanation for purpose of Migrator but it does not give any clue how it can be used in CI/CD Process. I want to run this tool from my Build Server ( for example VSTS)  as step in Release. So before application is deployed I want to run Migrator against given database - that's is missing part here - Migrator can not be configured for that scenario - or I miss something